# Linear analysis - linear mappings on sequence spaces

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, linear-transformations

Let $(v_n)_{n\geq1} \in l^2$ be a fixed bounded sequence of real numbers. Define a mapping $T$ on $l^2$ for every $x \in l^{\infty}$ using the formula
$T(a_1,a_2,...) = (v_1a_1,v_2a_2,...), x=(a_1,a_2,...) \in l^\infty$.

a) Verify that $Tx \in l^2$ for every $x \in l^2$

b) Find $||T||_{l^{\infty}\rightarrow l^2}$.

In the first question, I am having trouble showing that the sequence of partial sums ($s=\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_i$) converges (that is what I think I have to do). In the second question, I have no clue what it even means! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First question:  $x=(a_1,a_2,...) \in l^\infty$ means that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded. In general $\Sigma_{n=1}^\infty a_i$ does not converge.

Example: $(1,1,1,1,....) \in l^\infty$

In a) you have to verify that for each $ x=(a_1,a_2,...) \in l^\infty$ the series

$ \sum_{j=1}^{\infty }|v_ja_j|^2$ is convergent.

b) $||T||_{l^{\infty}\rightarrow l^2}$ is the operator norm

$||T||_{l^{\infty}\rightarrow l^2}= \sup \{||Tx||_2:  x \in l^\infty, ||x||_{\infty} \le 1\}$